# Issue when trying to boot Windows partition (Linux Mint/Windows 10 Dual Boot)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I recently partitioned my hard drive with about 22 GB of space for Linux Mint and the rest for Windows 10. From the GNU GRUB menu, I'm able to properly boot into Linux Mint by selecting the menu option for it. However, when I select the menu option for `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)`, I get the following error:

[image]

In order to get into windows, I have to go to system settings and change the boot order and while this workaround suffices for now, I think it would be better to just be able to boot both from the menu.

What could be causing the problem?

Here is an image of the boot menu:

[image]

Comment: Is that error from the Windows Boot Manager (which is what it looks like), or from Grub? If it's from WBM then Grub has done its bit and started to boot Windows.

Comment: I'm not really sure where the error is from exactly, but when I select the menu option for Windows Boot Manager, the error message shows up as in the image. Do you know how the file path could have been lost as it says?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280339/windows-8-wont-boot-via-grub-after-intalling-12-10-with-boot-repair